# Plugin Framework for Win-Rt

Tags: c#, plugins, windows-8, windows-runtime

I was looking at Microsoft.Composition but i don't think that is quite what i want.  I have a bunch of UserControls, that are each build into it's own assembly, but they each extend the same interface. What would be the best way to scan a directory, see what UserControl assembly is present and allow the program to use the controls that are present.
I would love to stay away from reflection.

Comment: Since you can't change the list of available controls, what is the point of doing this?

Comment: They are Callisto CustomDialog's

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to imply.  The only time the available assemblies can change is at install time, so you should know ahead of time what is available.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The Idea was for there to be several GUI's, Each for controlling a piece of equipment, and the server to be able to tell the tablet, when to activate the GUI.  The problem was, we have more pieces of equipment then GUI's, and they are all interfaced the same way.  Reflection seemed to be the way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDriver is a Interface that all drivers must extend, so we get the driver name, add the driver namespace and use the Activator to create the instance

```
Type driverType = Type.GetType(string.Format("Win8App.RDriver.Drivers.{0}", driver));
if (driverType != null)
{
    return (IDriver)Activator.CreateInstance(driverType);
}
log.Error(string.Format("Could not load driver Win8App.RDriver.Drivers.{0}", driver));
return null;
```